# Как удалить объекты из массива по ключу?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов:

```
[{
    "$$hashKey": "object:112",
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "57212d2b8cfc25c24e3e6ff8",
    "createDate": "2016-04-27T21:20:43.651Z",
    "domainid": "123",
    "form": "Обратный звонок",
    "inner": "<p>Имя: <b>Вася</b></p>"
}, {
    /* и так далее */
}]
```

Есть массив id:

```
["57212d368cfc25c24e3e6ff9", "57212d2b8cfc25c24e3e6ff8", /* И так далее */]
```

Как можно удалить все объекты с встречающимеся id из списка? 
То есть если в объекте в поле `_id` есть какое-то значение из второго массива, то этот объект должен удаляться из первого массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае подойдет метод [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), с небольшими приготовлениями.

Чтобы сократить действия по проверке есть ли проверяемый id в массиве, этот массив можно предварительно преобразовать в объект ключами которого будут элементы массива, например так

```
var ids = ["a","b","c"];
var idsMap = ids.reduce(function(map,id){map[id]=true; return map;},{});
```

Получим объект вида:

```
{
     "a": true,
     "b": true,
     "c": true
}
```

Далее используем метод `filter`

```
var filtered = objs.filter(function(el){
    return !idsMap[el._id];
});
```

В массиве `filtered` будут только элементы `_id` которых нет в массиве с `Id`

```js
var ids = ["a", "b", "c"];
var idsMap = ids.reduce(function(map, id) {
  map[id] = true;
  return map;
}, {});

var objs = [{
  _id: 'a',
  name: 1
}, {
  _id: 'f',
  name: 2
}, {
  _id: 'd',
  name: 3
}, {
  _id: 'b',
  name: 4
}, {
  _id: 'e',
  name: 5
}, {
  _id: 'c',
  name: 6
}];


var filtered = objs.filter(function(el) {
  return !idsMap[el._id];
});

document.write('Source:<pre>'+JSON.stringify(objs,null,2)+'</pre>')
document.write('Filtered:<pre>'+JSON.stringify(filtered,null,2)+'</pre>')
```

Также можно использоваться `thisArg` параметр в функции `filter`, что позволит избавиться от замыкания переменной

```js
var ids = ["a", "b", "c"];
var idsMap = ids.reduce(function(map, id) {
  map[id] = true;
  return map;
}, {});

var objs = [{
  _id: 'a',
  name: 1
}, {
  _id: 'f',
  name: 2
}, {
  _id: 'd',
  name: 3
}, {
  _id: 'b',
  name: 4
}, {
  _id: 'e',
  name: 5
}, {
  _id: 'c',
  name: 6
}];


var filtered = objs.filter(function(el) {
  return !this[el._id];
},idsMap);

document.write('Source:<pre>'+JSON.stringify(objs,null,2)+'</pre>')
document.write('Filtered:<pre>'+JSON.stringify(filtered,null,2)+'</pre>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю по поводу производительности данного способа, но результат есть :)

```js
var arr1 = [{
  _id: "333333333"
}, {
  _id: "444444444"
}, {
  _id: "555555555"
}];

var arr2 = ["345345345", "444444444", "543543543"];

arr1.forEach(function(item, i) {
  for (j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    if (item._id == arr2[j]) {
      arr1.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
});


console.log(arr1);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr1, undefined, 2);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: мапы для перебора массива плохо использовать..., мапы нужны чтобы создавать новые массивы из старых данных

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, да, вы правы, переделал на forEach

Comment: Вообще не очень хорошо менять массив по которому бежим в данный момент.

Comment: @Grundy, а чем нехорошо? Распишите подробнее какие неприятности от этого могут быть.

Comment: Замените в примере из вашего объекта в массиве `var arr2 = ["345345345", "444444444", "543543543"];` первый элемент на "333333333", чтобы получилось: `var arr2 = ["333333333", "444444444", "543543543"];`. Как вы думаете какой результат будет после выполнения скрипта?

Comment: @Grundy, мда, определённо есть над чем подумать :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, все дело в дырках, когда удалили элемент, индекс не должен меняться, поэтому при использовании `splice` для удаления в цикле обычно используют итерацию с конца. Так что в данном случае, лучше не использовать функции из array, а переписать все на циклы

Answer (score 1):

пример удаляет элемент из массива:

```
var my_array = ["a","b","c","k","d"];
var start_index = 3
var number_of_elements_to_remove = 1;
var removed_elements = my_array.splice(start_index, number_of_elements_to_remove);
console.log(removed_elements);//["k"]
console.log(my_array);    //["a","b","c","d"];
```